# class file not found

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've just closed my project and reopen it and now I'm facing new Error !

> error: cannot access TintableImageSourceView class file for 
>   android.support.v4.widget.TintableImageSourceView not found

It seems this line is occuring the error but I really don't know why :

```
 LottieAnimationView animationView = (LottieAnimationView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.animation_view);
            //  overlay = (RelativeLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.overlay);
            animationView.setImageAssetDelegate(new ImageAssetDelegate() {
                @Override
                public Bitmap fetchBitmap(LottieImageAsset asset) {
                    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
                    InputStream istr;
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    try {
                        istr = assetManager.open(asset.getFileName());
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // handle exception
                    }
                    return bitmap;
                }
            });
            animationView.setAnimation("data.json");
            animationView.loop(true);
```

as I said , project was working properly yesterday , and nothing changed in my code till today ! I've just reopen it today .

EDIT : 
app gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.8.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias '...'
            keyPassword '...'
            storeFile file('...')
            storePassword '...'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ymz.yma.setareitsim_seller"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "...",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug{
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    compile 'com.truizlop.fabreveallayout:library:1.0.0'
    // compile 'com.bartoszlipinski.flippablestackview:library:1.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
    compile 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabstrip:navigationtabstrip:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.roger.psdloadingview.library:Library:1.0.1'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.takusemba:spotlight:1.1.3'
    compile('com.github.badoualy:stepper-indicator:1.0.7') { exclude group: 'com.android.support' }
    compile('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
    compile('com.alibaba.android:ultraviewpager:1.0.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.jorgecastilloprz:fabprogresscircle:1.01@aar'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.8.3, 3.99.99]'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    compile 'com.github.iwgang:countdownview:2.1.6'
    // compile 'nl.psdcompany:duo-navigation-drawer:2.0.7'
    implementation project(':sep')
}
```

P.S : I've updated android studio to latest version , invalidate caches and clean project but not working !

SOLVED !

SOLUTION :
I've just shutdown the pc and let it go . after starting the pc and reopen the project problem was fixed ! it took my whole day to me .

Comment: Post your gradle file for your project also gradle root file.

Comment: @jantursky i edited my question

Comment: Try to update to the latest SDK version even with libraries like: compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"


dependencies {
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning and rebuilding the project

Comment: thank you for your reply , I've cleaned , rebuild , invalidate and clean caches ! not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm already face this type problem and for me solved that.
Just click in Android studio: `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`
After restart and indexing, hope all thing will be work.

And you also can do `Build -> Clean Project` then `Build -> Rebuild Project`

Comment: Oh I see, now a days I found android studio seem some error when I open again. but for me I did those task and works perfectly.